# Debian preseed late_command is not executed

Tags: debian, automated-install, preseed

On /var/log/installer/cdebconf/questions.dat  i says this:

```
Name: preseed/late_command
Template: preseed/late_command
Value: wget http://suportrecerca.barcelonamedia.org/Utilitats/preseed/postscript/post.sh \ -O /usr/sbin/post.sh; chmod 777 /usr/sbin/post.sh; /usr/sbin/post.sh
Owners: d-i
Flags: seen
```

I can download the post.sh script and looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
### postscript de veritat
#TODO
######
#
# config puppet
# VAS (puppet?)
# snmp (puppet?)
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get -y install htop vim
apt-get autoremove
# and more stuff that by now is not related
```

But when I try to exec htop or vim it's not installed.  Also the script must create some files but they do not appear.

I've been looking around and I'm not able to found a good aproach to this problem.

Any hits or suggestion?

many thanks.

Comment: In an unrelated note: Just use `d-i pkgsel/include string htop vim` in your preseed file instead of installing the packages in your `preseed/late_command`.

Comment: Thanks but I need to download some scripts and let them on special places. It's corporate stuff and they are not on the debian repos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work due to [changes](http://www.debian.org/devel/debian-installer/News/2006/20060315) in debian-installer. [Read the current docs](http://d-i.alioth.debian.org/manual/), particularly the sections on [custom commands](http://d-i.alioth.debian.org/manual/en.i386/apbs05.html#preseed-hooks) and [extra packages](http://d-i.alioth.debian.org/manual/en.i386/apbs04.html#preseed-pkgsel).